# What software with a good GUI can do normalization of a large matrix of spectroscopy data?

Tags: statistics, normalization, data-analysis

What software with a good GUI can do normalization of a large matrix of spectroscopy data? I have done that in Python codes and tried StatsDirect. What other software have implemented algorithms to perform data normalization on a Raman spectroscopy data or similar 300X5000 data table? is there any way to do it using SPSS, STATA, MiniTab, Statistica, SAS? thx.

Answer (score 0):

1. The SAS tools that you can try are: [SAS Enterprise Guide](http://support.sas.com/software/products/enterprise-guide/index.html) and [SAS Visual Analytics](https://www.sas.com/en_gb/software/visual-analytics.html). These are GUI / point & click tools but you also have the ability to write SAS code to do any transformation you want. If you have a student / academic email you can use them for free.
2. You can use [KNIME](https://www.knime.com/) which is an open source Analytics platform.

Comment: thanks, could you show a code to normalize data in JMP SAS and a tutorial on how to do this with KNIMe?

Comment: JMP is a different programming language to SAS programming.  You can find the JMP documentation here: https://www.jmp.com/en_us/support/jmp-documentation.html

Comment: Your question here is very generic, I recommend you split it to a couple of specific questions to each Tool / Platform you want.

Answer (score 0):

@player777 In Statistica it is as easy as right clicking a column and choosing standardize/normalize and it will scale the column to have zero mean and unit variance. I am not sure what Raman spectroscopic data looks like and are you looking for something else, may be a bit more complicated algo?
 In Statistica you can also code in python, R and C# as well as offload your work to a spark cluster by writing Scala scripts if you have access to a cluster. Let me know if you need further info,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me Matlab is the best- You can simply write Your own GUI and I was working with data 2000x2000 with plotting Gauss, Lorenz or whatever You wont- very quickly. You may do the same using Octave- it is also very good for matrix but slower than Matlab.